# error: illegal start of expression save = canvas.save(@Saveflags save) in andriod

Tags: android

How to call save with parameter method with integer value .
I am getting this error, as the save method accepts the saveflag interface annotation.
Then,why i am getting this error.
I am using targetversion 28 .
Please help to get the solution for this problem.

Comment: show the code, and the error which you get.

Comment: int save = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
if (mSlideOffset < 0.5f)
save = canvas.save(@Saveflags save);

Comment: method `Canvas.save()` does not have parameters

Comment: Canvas.save() ==> yes save method have no parameters.
But that overrided by passing parameter called
 public int save(@Saveflags int saveFlags) {
        return nSave(mNativeCanvasWrapper, saveFlags);
    }
So,How can i call this overrided method in separate class

Comment: Is that your own method? There is only one `save` method in `Canvas` documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#save()